# Run python scripts in a batch on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, batch-file

Please let me know if there is a way I can run multiple python scripts in a batch on Linux, like the way it is possible to run multiple python scripts in a batch using a .bat file on windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a script...

```
#!/bin/sh
# This file is called ~/script.sh

python script1.py
python script2.py
```

Make the script executable...

```
chmod +x ~/script.sh
```

Run the script...

```
~/script.sh
```

Comment: This doesn't work. My code: inside of script.py is `from tkinter import *` `root = Tk()`. I get an error when I run run bash script in terminal ./script.sh ......error: 

`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>`
   ` from tkinter import *`
`  File "/home/cooldudeabhi/PycharmProjects/tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>`
    `root = Tk()`
`NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined`